# Welcome to undefined?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notification-bar

So I just logged out of SO and this is what I was greeted by:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7131609/StackOverflow/undefined.PNG

Also I tested it on the other sites:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7131609/StackOverflow/undefined2.PNG
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7131609/StackOverflow/undefined3.PNG
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7131609/StackOverflow/undefined4.PNG

However I should note this bug does not affect meta (it just says first time here), or webapps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

minor deployment artifact. We're changing the new user message from..

> First time here? Check out the FAQ!

to..

> Welcome to {site description} -- check out the FAQ!

Where site description is in

```
Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
Q&A for system administrators and IT professionals
Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users
Q&A about the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites
Q&A for power users of web applications
Q&A about the Web Apps site
Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms
Q&A about the Gaming site
Q&A about apps for and development with the Stack Exchange API
```

(as of this writing)

Comment: Yeah I figured it was an update, just thought I would let you know. Also Good idea, I like having the `{site description}` in the banner. That should make the site's purpose much clearer to new users.